# Lock database, using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I use C#, EF and Microsoft SQL Server in my project. I need to lock the whole database on one of the machine to synchronize it with Active Directory.

Many machines have access to the database, so I need to prevent reading, inserting or updating my database from another machines.

Simple example, what I try to do now:

```
using (DB context = new DB())
using (var ts = context.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable))
{
    context.Database.Connection.Open();

    try
    {
         string sql = SQLProperties.getInstance().CurrentPropeties["User_Insert"];
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(10240);

         for (int chunkCount = 0; chunkCount < Math.Ceiling((decimal)count / commitCount); chunkCount++)
         {
             using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
             {
                 command.Transaction = (SqlTransaction)ts.UnderlyingTransaction;

                 for (var i = 1; i <= commitCount; i++)
                 {
                     string query = sql;
                     int ind = chunkCount * commitCount + i;

                     query = string.Format(query, ind);

                     sb.Append(query);
                     //fill command.Params
                 }

                 command.Connection = (SqlConnection)context.Database.Connection;
                 command.CommandText = sb.ToString();

                 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            sb.Clear();
        }

        ts.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         ts.Rollback();
    }
}
```

But when `ExecuteNonQuery()` is called, the query is sent to the database and executed. And when I prepare `SqlCommand`, another machine can read, insert or update data in database even I use single transaction. I need to disable it.

Also I need to do many another changes with data in tables in the database, so I want **lock the entire database during the synchronization**.

I know that in Server Management Studio I can use GO statement for batch SQL queries, but `SqlCommand` does not support this one statement. Also I try to send GO statement using this method:

```
ServerConnection svrConnection = new ServerConnection((SqlConnection)context.Database.Connection);
Server server = new Server(svrConnection);
int f = server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery("LOCK TABLES dbo.User WRITE");
```

But seems it doesn't work.

How can I do it from C# code?

Added: How can I **sync two possible transaction** which were started at the same time? Now I have issue when one transaction starts inserting user in table, and, after 500 users for example, another transaction inserts user and table contains mixed data from two transactions. How can I order them?

Comment: GO is NOT a t-sql statement. It is the default batch terminator in SSMS. What is your question?

Comment: I'm curious to know why you need to lock the entire database (or even an individual table within said database). Most modern database systems (SQL Server included) allow for pretty good concurrency. What phenomenon are you trying to prevent by locking the entire thing?

Comment: Synchronization can be started from two machines at the same time, but all of them have common data for synchronizing. I need lock some tables for preventing double inserted data. 
That's why I want to deny the access to tables. Synchronization data may contain more than 10 000+ users and emails, also need to delete old data or upgrade it to the new state.
Or can I build file with big count of sql queries and process it in one transaction to prevent database locking? SqlCommand has limit for parameters like a  2100 in C#.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to lock the database you could use:

```
ALTER DATABASE [xyz] SET SINGLE_USER
```

This will restrict the ability of other users to connect to the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think that this solution will be fine, but do I have possibility to lock some tables in the database?

Comment: If you want to issue locks on tables you should be able to but it is unneccesary as no other users will be allowed to do anything or connect.